# TSQL to combine a date field and a time field

Tags: t-sql

Using logparser to import IIS logs to a db results in one column that has the date value and a second field for time:

```
2010-05-25 00:00:00.000
```

and

```
2010-01-01 11:11:58.000
```

I'd like to code an `after insert` trigger that combines the 2 fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case somebody else stumbles on this thread (or in case the original poster still can use this answer), look into the TO_TIMESTAMP ( date , time  ) function in LogParser which lets you combine a date-only timestamp with a time-only timestamp into a full timestamp value... and saves you from having to convert in the db...

Answer (score 20):

You can just add the two values after casting them to DATE and TIME datatypes, if you're using SQL Server 2008 or later.  Here's an example.

```
declare @datet datetime;
set @datet = GETDATE();

select 
    @datet, 
    cast(@datet as date), 
    cast(@datet as time);

select 
    cast(cast(@datet as date) as datetime), 
    cast(cast(@datet as time) as datetime), 
    cast(cast(@datet as date) as datetime) + cast(cast(@datet as time) as datetime);
```

Comment: The Date and Time as datatypes seems much cleaner than pulling positions from a string. New to 08, you say. So you've got me the first 9 yards - i can update all rows in the table - how do I update just the inserted rows - looks like at a minimum i should be looking at 'INSERT BEFORE' instead of AFTER thx

Comment: If you can, avoid the trigger altogether and just add another column to the table as a computed column instead.  You can do this by using s statement like this: ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD DateAndTime (cast(cast(@datet as date) as datetime) + cast(cast(@datet as time) as datetime));

Comment: In my case I had a static time I wanted to tack on and was able to avoid the inner cast on the time portion.  So cast(cast(some_date_col as date) as datetime + cast('11:59:59 PM' as datetime) worked splendidly and was a little more concise.  ymmv

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Date varchar(23)
       ,@Time varchar(23)
       ,@Both datetime

SELECT @Date='2010-05-25 00:00:00.000'
      ,@Time='2010-01-01 11:11:58.000'

SELECT @Both=LEFT(@Date,10)+' '+RIGHT(@Time,12)

SELECT @Both
```

OUTPUT:

```
-----------------------
2010-05-25 11:11:58.000

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Set based:

```
DECLARE @INSERTED table(RowID int, DateOf varchar(23), TimeOf varchar(23), DateTimeOf datetime)

INSERT @INSERTED VALUES (1,'2010-05-25 00:00:00.000','2010-01-01 11:11:58.000',null)
INSERT @INSERTED VALUES (2,'2010-04-05 00:00:00.000','2010-01-01 12:34:56.789',null)
INSERT @INSERTED VALUES (3,'2010-03-15 00:00:00.000','2010-01-01 01:01:01.000',null)


UPDATE @INSERTED
    SET DateTimeOf=LEFT(DateOf,10)+' '+RIGHT(TimeOf,12)

SELECT * FROM @INSERTED
```

OUTPUT:

```
RowID   DateOf                  TimeOf                  DateTimeOf
------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
1       2010-05-25 00:00:00.000 2010-01-01 11:11:58.000 2010-05-25 11:11:58.000
2       2010-04-05 00:00:00.000 2010-01-01 12:34:56.789 2010-04-05 12:34:56.790
3       2010-03-15 00:00:00.000 2010-01-01 01:01:01.000 2010-03-15 01:01:01.000

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a choice to add the output into a new column, you can also make that new column as a computed column and define it to combine those 2 columns (at a design time).

Dev